# Add x and y labels to a pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Suppose I have the following code that plots something very simple using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
values = [[1, 2], [2, 5]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=['Type A', 'Type B'], 
                   index=['Index 1', 'Index 2'])
df2.plot(lw=2, colormap='jet', marker='.', markersize=10, 
         title='Video streaming dropout by category')
```

[image: Output]

How do I easily set x and y-labels while preserving my ability to use specific colormaps? I noticed that the `plot()` wrapper for pandas DataFrames doesn't take any parameters specific for that.

Comment: This is now the correct [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65875329/7758804)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In Pandas *version 1.10* you can use parameters `xlabel` and `ylabel` in the method `plot`:

```
df.plot(xlabel='X Label', ylabel='Y Label', title='Plot Title')
```

[image]

Answer (score 444):

The `df.plot()` function returns a `matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot` object. You can set the labels on that object.

```
ax = df2.plot(lw=2, colormap='jet', marker='.', markersize=10, title='Video streaming dropout by category')
ax.set_xlabel("x label")
ax.set_ylabel("y label")
```

[image]

Or, more succinctly: `ax.set(xlabel="x label", ylabel="y label")`.

Alternatively, the index x-axis label is automatically set to the Index name, if it has one. so `df2.index.name = 'x label'` would work too.

Comment: set_xlabel or set_ylabel are not working for pandas 0.25.1. Howerver, ax.set(xlabel="x label", ylabel="y label") does.

Answer (score 64):

You can use do it like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd

plt.figure()
values = [[1, 2], [2, 5]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=['Type A', 'Type B'], 
                   index=['Index 1', 'Index 2'])
df2.plot(lw=2, colormap='jet', marker='.', markersize=10,
         title='Video streaming dropout by category')
plt.xlabel('xlabel')
plt.ylabel('ylabel')
plt.show()
```

Obviously you have to replace the strings 'xlabel' and 'ylabel' with what you want them to be.

Comment: Also note, you have to call `plt.xlabel()` etc. after `df.plot()`, not before, because otherwise you get two plots - the calls will modify a "previous" plot. Same thing goes for `plt.title()`.

Answer (score 33):

If you label the columns and index of your DataFrame, pandas will automatically supply appropriate labels:

```
import pandas as pd
values = [[1, 2], [2, 5]]
df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=['Type A', 'Type B'], 
                  index=['Index 1', 'Index 2'])
df.columns.name = 'Type'
df.index.name = 'Index'
df.plot(lw=2, colormap='jet', marker='.', markersize=10, 
        title='Video streaming dropout by category')
```

[image]

In this case, you'll still need to supply y-labels manually (e.g., via `plt.ylabel` as shown in the other answers).

Comment: currently, that 'automatic supply from DataFrame' doesn't work. I just tried it (pandas version 0.16.0, matplotlib 1.4.3) and the plot generates correctly, but with no labels on the axes.

Comment: @szeitlin could you please file a bug report on the pandas github page? https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues

Comment: you know what, today at least the xlabel is working. maybe there was something strange about the dataframe I was using yesterday (?). if I can reproduce it, I will file it!

Answer (score 31):

It is possible to set both labels together with `axis.set` function. Look for the example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
values = [[1,2], [2,5]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=['Type A', 'Type B'], index=['Index 1','Index 2'])
ax = df2.plot(lw=2,colormap='jet',marker='.',markersize=10,title='Video streaming dropout by category')
# set labels for both axes
ax.set(xlabel='x axis', ylabel='y axis')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I like the `.set(xlabel='x axis', ylabel='y axis')` solution because it lets me put it all in one line, unlike the set_xlabel and set_ylabel plot methods. I wonder why they all (including the set method, by the way) don't return the plot object or at least something inherited from it.

Answer (score 16):

For cases where you use `pandas.DataFrame.hist`:

```
plt = df.Column_A.hist(bins=10)
```

Note that you get an ARRAY of plots, rather than a plot.  Thus to set the x label you will need to do something like this

```
plt[0][0].set_xlabel("column A")
```

Answer (score 14):

what about ...

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

values = [[1,2], [2,5]]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=['Type A', 'Type B'], index=['Index 1','Index 2'])

(df2.plot(lw=2,
          colormap='jet',
          marker='.',
          markersize=10,
          title='Video streaming dropout by category')
    .set(xlabel='x axis',
         ylabel='y axis'))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

`pandas` uses `matplotlib` for basic dataframe plots. So, if you are using `pandas` for basic plot you can use matplotlib for plot customization. However, I propose an alternative method here using `seaborn` which allows more customization of the plot while not going into the basic level of `matplotlib`.

**Working Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
values = [[1, 2], [2, 5]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=['Type A', 'Type B'], 
                   index=['Index 1', 'Index 2'])
ax= sns.lineplot(data=df2, markers= True)
ax.set(xlabel='xlabel', ylabel='ylabel', title='Video streaming dropout by category')
```

[image]

Comment: This specific use case doesn't seem like a reason to use seaborn. As shown in [the top-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21487560/1711796), you can call `set` directly on the value returned from `DataFrame.plot` (which is very similar to the code you've shown here, except without the added dependency).