# How to set and display x/y label with pandas plot in ipython notebook?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, plot, jupyter-notebook

When I plot a pandas Series in **ipython notebook** and setting the label as suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487329/add-x-and-y-labels-to-a-pandas-plot) answer:

```
plt1=some_series.plot(marker='o', title='Count Distribution')
plt1.set_xlabel='x Count'
plt1.set_ylabel='y Frequecy'
```

and evaluate the cell. The plot shows with the title, but not the x or y labels. How can I do this in ipython notebook?

And the comment by Chrispy on that post

> Is there a particular reason why x and y labels can't be added as arguments to pd.plot()?

might also be a related issue worth answering.

EDIT:
Thanks, now I know the error, my fault. But why doesn' t it throw me an error on the value assignment to methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [post you link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21487560/1634191), it shows that `set_xlabel/set_ylabel` are methods, not attributes.  Therefore they should be called (using parentheses):

```
plt1 = some_series.plot(marker='o', title='Count Distribution')
plt1.set_xlabel('x Count')
plt1.set_ylabel('y Frequency')
```

Comment: Thanks. I must be too tired when doing this. Why doesn' t it give me an error message?

Comment: By default, `plt1.set_xlabel` points to a function (`Axes.set_xlabel()` which calls something like `Axes.xaxis.set_label_text()`). You simply overwrote that and set `plt1.set_xlabel` to point to the string `'x Count'`.