# Getting an error while plotting sum and average in pandas

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

```
total_income_language = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('language')['gross'].sum())   
average_income_language = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('language')['gross'].mean()) 



plt.bar(total_income_language.index, total_income_language["gross"],  
                 label="Total Income of Language")
plt.bar(average_income_language.index, average_income_language["gross"], 
                 label="Average Income of Language")

plt.xlabel("Language")

plt.ylabel("Log Dollar Values(Gross)")
```

I want to plot the sum and average for each and every languages. I'm not sure if my code does what I wanted. And I'm getting an error while trying to plot this. I'm not sure where did I messed up on the coding. I need some assistance.

[Here's the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yr9qG.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregation by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html), rename columns by `dict` and plot by [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html).

Last set labels by [`ax.set`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21487560/2901002).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'language':['en','de','en','de','sk','sk'],
                   'gross':[10,20,30,40,50,60]})

print (df)
   gross language
0     10       en
1     20       de
2     30       en
3     40       de
4     50       sk
5     60       sk

d = {'mean':'Average Income of Language','sum':'Total Income of Language'}
df1 = df.groupby('language')['gross'].agg(['sum','mean']).rename(columns=d)
print (df1)
          Total Income of Language  Average Income of Language
language                                                      
de                              60                          30
en                              40                          20
sk                             110                          55

ax = df1.plot.bar()
ax.set(xlabel='Language', ylabel='Log Dollar Values(Gross)')
```

[image: graph]

If want rotate labels of `axis x`:

```
ax = df1.plot.bar(rot=0)
ax.set(xlabel='Language', ylabel='Log Dollar Values(Gross)')
```

[image: graph1]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
df.groupby('language')['gross'].sum()
```

Try this:

```
df.groupby('language').sum()
```

And similarly with `mean()`. That should get your code closer to running.

Calling the `groupby()` method of a DataFrame yields a `groupby` object upon which you then need to call an aggregation function, like `sum`, `mean`, or `agg`. The `groupby` documentation is really great: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html

Also, you might be able to achieve your desired output in two lines:

```
df.groupby('language').sum().plot(kind='bar')
df.groupby('language').mean().plot(kind='bar')
```