# Why can't I set x and y labels as arguments to pd.plot(), whereas I can easily set similar stuff, such as title?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I'm printing various things with pandas, using the inbuilt `plot` command, such as `my_dataframe.plot()` followed by `plt.show()` in ipython.

Now this is a very easy and convenient way to visualize stuff, and given that I do postprocessing on the SVG file anyways, I don't care too much about details of the plot.

However, I need a title, a legend and labels for the x and y axis on the plot, both as a reminder to myself about what is what, and for quickly sending some stuff to other folks, without having to add a "Oh, and BTW, the x axis is hours this time, y is meters as always, but blue now is sample B…" line to the email.

I figured out how to do this in an easy way (see below) and I'm also aware about the various powerful things I could do with `ax`, but it took me a while to get to my "easy" solution, and I'm staying away from `ax` because there is way too much stuff going on that I neither need nor understand.

I do understand why one would want all the powerful options of `ax`, but I do not understand why such a simply option is not included in pandas plotting function. And it seems like I'm not the only one. User Chrispy for example posted this highly rated comment:

> is there a particular reason why x and y labels can't be added as arguments to `pd.plot()`? Given the additional concision of `pd.plot()` over `plt.plot()` it seems it would make sense to make it even more succinct instead of having to call `ax.set_ylabel()`

on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487329/add-x-and-y-labels-to-a-pandas-plot), but got no further comments. Hence I'm blatantly stealing this question.

Why does `plt.plot()` include legends by default and also easily lets me add a title (`my_df.plot(title = 'check out my cool plot')`), but the logical next step (`my_df.plot(ylabel = 'size in meters')`) results in `TypeError: There is no Line2D property "ylabel"`?

Am I missing something or is there a reason for this oversight?

**Example code:**

This works when I implement it in my real file and run it with `run workflow.py` in ipython, but I cant reproduce it when copy-pasting the code. Either my labels get ignored, or it downright fails:

**EDIT:**

*Originally I had `plt.xlabel = 'time in seconds'` in my example here, which did not work, but I had the correct `plt.xlabel('time in seconds')` in my real code, which of course did work.*

```
times = np.arange(0,43200,60)
my_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(times)), index = times)
my_df.plot(title = 'just some random data')    #this works
#my_df.plot(title = 'just some random data', ylabel = 'size in meters', xlabel = 'time in seconds')    #this seems like the logical next step, but it errors
plt.ylabel('size in meters')
plt.xlabel('time in seconds')
```

This seems like the most easy/minimal solution with `axes`, using @Johannes solution, but I think this (see comments to the answer) is also a good illustration why I would like to not having to bother myself with `axes`:

```
axes = my_df.plot(title = 'just some random data')
axes.set_ylabel('size in meters')
axes.set_xlabel('time in seconds')
```

Also, I can set the title another way, but there is only one option for the labels, which is what's confusing me:

```
axes = my_df.plot()
axes.set_title('just some random data')
axes.set_ylabel('size in meters')
axes.set_xlabel('time in seconds')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, there is no particular reason for the pandas plotting command not to also include keyword arguments for the labels, just as for the title.
This option could well be implemented, **but it isn't**. To speculate about the reasons will not lead anywhere but there is an issue about it at the [pandas issue tracker](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9093).

Concerning the actual problem, there are several ways to set labels to the axes. Three possible methods are listed below. Note that in the question as well as in the other answer there appear some non working methods.

Especially `ax.xlabel()` does not exist. Neither does `plt.ylabel = 'size in meters'` make any sense, since it *overwrites*  the `ylabel` method instead of *using*  it.

Working options:

#### `ax.set_xlabel()`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

times = np.arange(0,43200,60)
my_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(times)), index = times)
ax = my_df.plot(title = 'just some random data')

ax.set_ylabel('size in meters')
ax.set_xlabel('time in seconds')

plt.show()
```

#### `ax.set()`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

times = np.arange(0,43200,60)
my_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(times)), index = times)
ax = my_df.plot(title = 'just some random data')
ax.set(xlabel='time in seconds', ylabel='size in meters')

plt.show()
```

#### `plt.xlabel()`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

times = np.arange(0,43200,60)
my_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(times)), index = times)
my_df.plot(title = 'just some random data')

plt.ylabel('size in meters')
plt.xlabel('time in seconds')

plt.show()
```

#### `plt.setp()`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

times = np.arange(0,43200,60)
my_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(times)), index = times)
ax = my_df.plot(title = 'just some random data')

plt.setp(ax,xlabel='time in seconds', ylabel='size in meters')

plt.show()
```

Comment: I see. I figured there might be a reason that I am simply overlooking, but seems like there is none. Maybe I'll suggest it on github, if I can find the time and my login data for it. The `plt.ylabel = 'size in meters'` probably sneaked in while going back and forth between my real script and the MWE, due to the confusing that caused me to ask the question in the first place.

Comment: As you can see [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9093) that is no new issue.

Comment: If you are plotting a  pandas series the ```plt.setp()``` works

Answer (score 0):

`df.plot()` returns a list of [Axes](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html) objects (one for each subplot). Those have `.set_xlabel()` and `.set_ylabel()` methods.

Do something like this:

```
times = np.arange(0,43200,60)
my_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(times)), index = times)
axes = my_df.plot(title = 'just some random data')
axes[0].ylabel('size in meters')
axes[0].xlabel('time in seconds')
```

Plots are no objects, instead the `plot` function just creates `Line` objects. Since you can have multiple lines in a single `Axes` object but only one pair of labels, it makes sense that the labels are properties of the axes and not of the lines.

Comment: But can't I also have multiple labels (e.g. secondary y-axis)? And I can't set multiple titles anyways, so why not also allow me to set the labels this way? And your example ends with `TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object does not support indexing` for me. Shouldn't it be `axes.set_ylabel =...`? And I can also use `axes.set_title=...`, so it would be logical to assume that it also behaves the same for `pd.plot()`

Comment: You can have multiple y-axis, but not more than two and its implemented as a special case. And it looks like `plot` returns a single `Axes` object instead of a one-element-list when there is only one subplot. Try to omit the `[0]` and just go for `axes.ylabel('size in meters')` etc.

Comment: Omitting the `[0]` just does not plot anything. `axes.set_ylabel = 'size in meters'` does work however.