# The X axis is not shown after ploting the data in python

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

[image]

[image]

When I tried to plot the the excel file, The graph did not show the X axis. 
Does anyone can help?

Thanks in advance

```
x=data['hour_formatted']

y=data['01_aug_18']

plt.plot (x, y)

plt.show()
```

Comment: What do you mean, did not show the X axis?

Comment: What is your error message? Does it not "find" the defined column/row X? Or is the result in plt.show() empty? If you get an error for the X definition (hour_formatted), then you probably misspelled. If plt.show() is empty, then you don't have any data in that field.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've attached the picture

Comment: @ItamarMushkin  I have attached the photo of my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a better solution, but try this:

```
data.set_index('hour_formatted')['01_aug_18'].plot()
```

It worked on my end and shows values properly, axis labels and everything.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The code that you provide is worked. @Itamar Mushkin

Comment: but how should I put name for X and Y axis? @ItamarMushkin

Comment: @Alisha The X axis should have the name of the index column (`'hour_formatted'` in this case). If you want to change them, call `plt.xlabel('new x label')` and `plt.ylabel('new y label')`

Comment: If the answer answered your question, please mark is as accepted (with the little green V) so it's visible that it's closed

Comment: Also, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487329/add-x-and-y-labels-to-a-pandas-plot

Comment: I dont know how to marked your answer, can you please tell me how? can you also give help for another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57584172/how-to-plot-bar-chart-for-data-with-1440-rows-%c3%97-297-columns

Comment: There's a little grey V to the left of the question. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Can you please help me in this case as well?  
 Thanks in advance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57584172/how-to-plot-bar-chart-for-data-with-1440-rows-%c3%97-297-columns