# How to plot the graph in more accurate way?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have a data set that consists of `1440 rows × 297 columns`. I tried to plot `03_jan_2018` in terms of Time(X-Axis) and Density (Y-Axis),  but I'm faced with a problem. The outcome graph is not enough clear and also the X-Axis is not appeared!!

I would like to make  [something like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCEsn.png)

[image]

But I'm ending up with this:

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix for this is to increase the figure size.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(80,40))
plt.plot(data.hour_formatted, data['03_jan_18'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but non of these codes solved the problem. (See the images please)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `plt.xticks(np.arange(0,25,6))` to select just the hours that you want.  It looks like it's trying to put in too many of them by default, and really you want just a handful of values (in this case only every 6 hours has a tick).  Tune the range value to just give the ones you want.

Comment: Ok what happened?  Did it throw an error or is the text still black or what?

Comment: Yes the text is still black.

Comment: What does the output look like when you just output `data.hour_formatted`?  Like give me `data.hour_formatted[-5:]`.

Answer (score 0):

The x-axis has appeared, but it seems that you're facing the same problem as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49231052/datetime-x-axis-matplotlib-labels-causing-uncontrolled-overlap/49232703#49232703). Anyway, I'll show you how you can get what you want and also avoid possible problems with the x-axis notations.

**Plot 1:**

[image]

**Code 1:**

```
# imports
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# random data or other data sources
np.random.seed(123)
rows = 1440
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(-1,1,size=(rows, 2)),
                  index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1440),
                    columns=list('AB'))

df['A'] = df['A'].cumsum()
df['B'] = df['B'].cumsum()

# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
t = df.index
ax.plot(t, df['A'])
ax.plot(t, df['B'], color='red')
```

You can also edit and adjust the axis notations like this:

**Plot 2:**

[image]

**Code 2:**

```
# imports
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# random data or other data sources
np.random.seed(123)
rows = 1440
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(-1,1,size=(rows, 2)),
                  index=pd.date_range('1/1/2020', periods=1440),
                    columns=list('AB'))

df['A'] = df['A'].cumsum()
df['B'] = df['B'].cumsum()

# Make a list of empty myLabels
myLabels = ['']*len(df.index)

# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
t = df.index
ax.plot(t, df['A'])
ax.plot(t, df['B'], color='red')

# Set labels on every Nth element in myLabels specified by the interval variable
myLabels = ['']*len(df.index)
interval = 2
myLabels[::interval] = [item.strftime('%Y - %m - %d') for item in df.index[::interval]]
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(myLabels))
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

# Tilt the labels
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=30, fontsize=10)
plt.show()
```