# Adding a label to pandas dataframe boxplot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, legend, boxplot

I've got a dataframe with a column titled label containing 4 unique text values of which are categorical in nature e.g Kitchen Appliances, Electronics, Women's Fashion, Stationary. Now, with the code below, I've got 4 different box plots which tells me the word frequency in each of the category but there's no indication as to which box plot represents which label/category, how do I go about labelling the boxplots with their respective categories?

```
train_data.groupby(['label'])[['word_count']].plot(
kind='box', vert=False, figsize=(12,3), use_index=True, title="Vizualizing Frequency Distributions"]);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487329/add-x-and-y-labels-to-a-pandas-plot

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

train_data.groupby(['label']).boxplot(column=['word_count'], vert=False)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

which produces

[image]