# How do you add (x,y) labels to a pandas matplotlib figure?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

So I have a plot but I do not get how to add data labels to my figures. I get the desired plots but I would like to see the y-value for each point. Here is the code:

```
list_of_centers=os.listdir("./")
for i in range(len(list_of_centers)):

    xls = pd.ExcelFile("./"+list_of_centers[i])
    for j in range(len(xls.sheet_names)):

        df=pd.read_excel("./"+list_of_centers[i])
        df=df.drop(columns=['Y', 'C','O','Y_C','Y_O'])
        df=df.set_index('Date')
        lines = df.plot.line(title=list_of_centers[i][:-5]+"_"+xls.sheet_names[j])


    #add labels


        plt.savefig("./"+list_of_centers[i] 
        [:-5]+"_"+xls.sheet_names[j]+".png")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following, just add it under `#add labels` (Also see: [Add x and y labels to a pandas plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487329/add-x-and-y-labels-to-a-pandas-plot))

```
lines.set_xlabel("x label")
lines.set_ylabel("y label")
```