# Proportional bar plot in Python

Tags: python, bar-chart

I have a data set like this.

```
Customer_ID Country Gender Premium_account
C_01        A      M       Yes
C_02        A      F       No
C_03        A      F       Yes
C_04        A      M       Yes
C_05        A      M       No
C_06        B      M       No
C_07        B      M       No
C_08        B      M       Yes
C_09        B      F       Yes
C_10        B      F       No
C_11        B      F       No
```

Now I would like to plot for the `Premium_account` percentage for each `Gender` and separate by `Country`. I wonder how could I generate a proportional bar plot like in the attached image using Python packages. I am actually not sure about which packages I should use for this, hence I really cannot provide any coding of mine so far. I would appreciate any help that you can provide. Thanks in advance!
[Proportional bar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3kaP.png)

Comment: Ideally you should provide some code to show what you've tried.  Can you at least specify a bit more about what libraries you're using (`pandas` will handle this very well) and how you want the plot (e.g. which of `Customer_ID`, `Country` and `Gender` do you want to plot `Premium_Account` against?

Comment: Thank you Chris for your suggestion. I have updated the question accordingly. However, I really dont know which approach I should take for this problem, hence, I cannot provide any coding of mine. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: ```matplotlib``` is great for plotting graphs. Found a stacked graph usage here: https://python-graph-gallery.com/13-percent-stacked-barplot/

Comment: thank you @drd. It's a very nice suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to get the desired result.

#### Imports and create dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

data = """Customer_ID Country Gender Premium_account
C_01 A M Yes
C_02 A F No
C_03 A F Yes
C_04 A M Yes
C_05 A M No
C_06 B M No
C_07 B M No
C_08 B M Yes
C_09 B F Yes
C_10 B F No
C_11 B F No"""

df = pd.DataFrame([x.split(' ') for x in data.split('\n')[1:]])
df.columns = data.split('\n')[0].split(' ')
```

#### Solution

First we map the `Premium_account` and `Gender` columns to binary, so that we can do maths with them.

```
df.Premium_account = df.Premium_account.map({'Yes': 1, 'No': 0})
df.Gender = df.Gender.map({'F': 1, 'M': 0})
df

    Customer_ID Country  Gender  Premium_account
0         C_01       A       0                1
1         C_02       A       1                0
2         C_03       A       1                1
3         C_04       A       0                1
4         C_05       A       0                0
5         C_06       B       0                0
6         C_07       B       0                0
7         C_08       B       0                1
8         C_09       B       1                1
9         C_10       B       1                0
10        C_11       B       1                0
```

Next, we compute the proportions of people who have a premium account for each country by gender, using `pandas`' `groupby` method.

```
account_proportions = ((df
                       .groupby(['Country', 'Gender'])
                       .Premium_account.sum() / df.Premium_account.sum())
                       .unstack('Gender')
)
account_proportions

Gender     0    1
Country          
A        0.4  0.2
B        0.2  0.2
```

Next, we normalise the dataframe row-wise.  This is what gives us a proportional plot instead of just a stacked bar plot.

```
account_proportions = account_proportions.div(account_proportions.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
account_proportions

Gender     0    1
Country          
A        0.4  0.2
B        0.2  0.2
```

Lastly, we can use `pandas`' own built in plotting method to plot a stacked bar chart.  Note that we save the axis object that is returned by the `plot.bar()` method, so that we can fix the legend entries back to 'Male' and 'Female'.  We're also specifying the title as part of the call to `plot.bar()`.  We also use the `rot` argument to make sure the x-axis labels are as desired.

```
ax = account_proportions.plot.bar(stacked='True',
                                  title='Premium Account Customer Plot',
                                  rot=0)
ax.legend(['Male', 'Female'])
```

[image: Premium_Account_Proportional_Plot]

Of course, there are other things that could be done, like [changing colours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927715/how-to-give-a-pandas-matplotlib-bar-graph-custom-colors) or [adding a y-axis label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487329/add-x-and-y-labels-to-a-pandas-plot) (please add a y-axis label) but this will get you most of the way.